# How to use REST API (or preferably Restforce) to upsert and only update when field is blank?

Tags: rest-api, api, update, upsert

I want to upsert Leads with the following rules:

1. Match by Email
2. If match is found, only update fields that are blank.

Is it possible to do this by using API `upsert`?

Is it possible to do it with `Restforce`?

If not, how to update only blank fields?

Apparently there is no tag for Restforce: https://github.com/restforce/restforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this by using API upsert?

No. Any changes you submit will alter the existing record, if any.

> If match is found, only update fields that are blank.

Again, see above.

> If not, how to update only blank fields?

You would still need to query the record(s) and update accordingly. Or use a custom rest service. Either way, anything you submit will result in updates to an existing record if one is found.